# There's snark, and then there's

Tags: discussion

insults, like this (in a comment made to a user whose first name is "Karthik"):

> @Kar Thick - please read out FAQ so that you understand the nature of this site before post anything at all.

My style might not be as smooth and welcoming of stupidity and laziness as some, but I do try and make it a point to play the ball, not the man.  I'm fairly sure I've *never* "creatively" mistyped a user's name to turn it into an insult, and if I have, I'll make a full public apology, directly to the user involved, if necessary, for having done so.

I flagged for mod attention, but then I decided, given the recent "war on snark", that it was worth raising here for wider attention and discussion.

Comment: You're right - that was out of order - I'm sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Having many times asked a poster to read the FAQ before posting again I have absolutely no trouble with that part.

The name bit is a whole other matter. If it was an honest mistake it's easily fixed with a quick edit or, if the edit period has expired, a flag to the mods asking them to make the correction. If it was a deliberate attempt to create an insult then it's a whole other matter. Either way, had I seen it I would most certainly have flagged it as offensive.

Maybe I'm reading it wrong but Chopper3's comment to the question makes me believe he was the poster of the comment under discussion. I find this behaviour unacceptable from anyone and absolutely inexcusable from a moderator. @Chopper3, if I've read that correctly I suggest that maybe it's time to rethink your level of involvement, at least for a while. You have certainly been showing signs of stress lately. Slow down and take it a bit easier. You're too valuable to SF to burn out.

Answer (score 6):

If the point is that the users name was turned into something else, yeah, I think that's a bit too far. Turning someones name is very highschool bully. Even if you're going to be condescending and even rude, you shouldn't belittle someone's name (especially if it's a "real" name, not a screen name, but the same still applies).

Answer (score 1):

First, can it *please* not be "The War on Snark". We've got enough drummed up "wars", though you might not be as familiar with as many being outside the United States of Wars on Everything (aka the USA).

While I agree that this particular instance is clearly over the proverbial line. I do not agree with calling these examples out publicly. Absolutely it is your right, if not your duty as a member of this community, to flag such comments. Mods, or higher, can deal with each case, or repeat offenders, as is appropriate. Collecting the community for witch hunts against individuals does nobody good.

Comment: Hah, the Chaser did a [War on Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chaser%27s_War_on_Everything) in Australia. It was amusing.

Comment: Jeff Atwood seems to disagree with you on specificity: "can you provide some specific examples? I find it difficult to talk about this stuff in the abstract."  Also, I've previously been told to raise such issues here, given the circumstances in this specific case.